# Plotting a 3 dimensional bar graph in Mathematica involving three axes of data

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

So I am fairly new to Mathematica and I have been having trouble finding a way of displaying three dimensional data in a bar structure in Mathematica. However, the best that I can do to represent my data. 
My data is formatted in a way that I have a three coordinate structure for all of the points but I want to have each individual point represented. The data is as follows:

```
{0, 220, 0.05}, {0, 230, 0.33}, {0, 230, 0}, {0, 230, 0}, 
{0, 250, 1.04}, {0, 250, 0.26}, {0, 250, 1.01}, {0, 250, 4.83}, {0, 250, 0},
{0, 270, 2.69}, {10, 220, 0.6}, {10, 240, 1.28}, {10, 250, 0.97},
{15, 250, 0.25}, {15, 270, 3.52}
```

How can I make the graph a three dimensional graph with each coordinate point (all three axes) represented in its individual bar on the graph as opposed to a plane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure what you are after -- note `ListPlot3D` doesn't work really right because some of your points are on top of each other..

```
 Show[{ListPlot3D[data ], Graphics3D[{PointSize[.1], Point[data]}]}]
```

[image]

```
 Show[Graphics3D@{Cuboid[{Append[#[[1 ;; 2]], 0] +
         {2, 2, 0}, # - {2, 2, 0}}] & /@ data}, Axes -> True, 
        AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}},
        BoxRatios -> {1, 2, .5}]
```

[image]

Comment: Oh this makes much more sense. I didnt realize that some of the data was on top of itself. it looks like the last example was the most useful for my project. Thanks so much! However, is it possible to label the axes?

Comment: try `Axes->True` option to`Show`

Answer (score 0):

```
ListPointPlot3D[{{0, 220, 0.05}, {0, 230, 0.33}, {0, 230, 0}, {0, 230,
0}, {0, 250, 1.04}, {0, 250, 0.26}, {0, 250, 1.01}, {0, 250, 
4.83}, {0, 250, 0}, {0, 270, 2.69}, {10, 220, 0.6}, {10, 240, 
1.28}, {10, 250, 0.97}, {15, 250, 0.25}, {15, 270, 3.52}}, 
Filling -> Bottom, DataRange -> All]
```

Is this what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I was hoping to have it look similar to a list plot 3D except with bars instead of geometric sloped plane. However, whenever I plot it as such even with the iteration being 0, I will get fragmented and uneven bars.